# Error in a javascript ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I have a problem with an AJAX request (POST method) with pure Javascript.

I have the following function:

```
function ajaxPost(page, fields) {
    XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHR.open("POST", page, false);
    XHR.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    if(XHR.readyState == 4 && XHR.status == 200) {
        return XHR.responseText;
    }
    XHR.send(fields);
}
```

and the page where I need to do an ajax request I make the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajax = ajaxPost("ajax/ajax.php", "var1=bla&var2=blabla");
    alert(ajax);
</script>
```

While in ajax/ajax.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['var1') && isset($_POST['var2'])) {
        echo var1 . " " . var2;
    }
?>
```

But the alert displays the value "undefined", where is that wrong?

Comment: `$_POST` should be `$_GET` since you're using `var1=bla&var2=blabla` being a GET method.

Comment: But I have absolutely no need to use the POST method, how should I do in this case?

Comment: Whatever you say. Did you try it?

Comment: `if($_GET['var1'] && $_GET['var2'])` like I said above.

Comment: I tried to change from `$ _POST` to `$ _GET`, but the alert always shows `undefined`

Comment: This `var1=bla&var2=blabla` needs to be `?var1=bla&var2=blabla` missing an `?` that should fix it all. Once it does, let me know, I will make it an answer.

Comment: So, did that ^ work? It should.

Comment: I tried to change (in the function ajaxPost) the return `XHR.responseText` with an alert of this and everything works. Even leaving the `$ _POST` in `ajax / ajax.php` ... Even if it works does not suit me because I would like the text I returned, so I could handle it.

Comment: I had not put the `?` but still does not work

Comment: Give me a minute, I think I know.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your ajax/ajax.php :

```
<?php
    if($_GET['var1'] && $_GET['var2']) {
        echo var1 . " " . var2;
    }
?>
```